# How to measure light?

Tags: linux, hardware, monitors, sensors, brightness

I've got a Dell Latitude E6410 notebook which changes lcd light intensity in response to ambient light levels, so it has to have some photocell. How can I access the data from this photocell? I tried different google searches like lux meter, light intensity monitor and so on and did not find a single right thing.

Comment: I'd start my investigations with lspci, lsusb etc. Maybe you can see the device there.

Comment: To follow up on @January's comment, use `qdbusviewer` to check the device and simultaneously access its stats through D-Bus. This of course assumes you use Linux.

Answer (score 6):

Try:

```
find /proc /sys | grep -ie brightness -e light -e lux -e lumin
```

On this laptop (a MacBookPro), it reveals (among other things):

```
/sys/devices/platform/applesmc.768/light
```

which is neither over PCI or USB.

You could try the same after

```
sudo modprobe -a tsl2550 isl29003 isl29020 apds9802als apds990x bh1770glc bh1780gli
```

which are drivers for various ambient light sensors.

You could also try `sensors-detect` or `i2cdetect` and see what they find. Possibly some information is made available from the BIOS (see `dmidecode`, `acpidump`, `acpiextract`, `iasl`).

Comment: It outputs lot of data http://pastebin.com/TuqsfBG7 How can i use this?

Comment: Not much interesting in there. I've edited my answer with more words to search (lux, lumin) and more things to try.

Comment: What does `lspci -Q` output?

Answer (score 2):

A few links:

- http://www.kernel.org/doc/menuconfig/drivers-misc-Kconfig.html (to access data from the sensor the kernel must know about the device!)
- http://forum.notebookreview.com/dell-latitude-vostro-precision/475324-e6410-owners-thread-91.html

I do not know what the ALS is in your particular case, but as @January said, you may start from the `lspci -Q` utility output (which requires an Internet connection to query/requery all IDs - use `-q` for unknown IDs only).